# Rails migration, references `unique: true` isn't generating `unique: true` in schema causing constancy_fail check to fail

Tags: ruby, activerecord, rails-migrations, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I have the following migration

```
class CreateBooking < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :bookings do |t|
      t.integer :day_period, default: 0
      t.references :service, foreign_key: true, unique: true, dependent: :destroy, index: true
    end
  end
end
```

and it generates the following schema:

```
  create_table "bookings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "day_period", default: 0
    t.bigint "service_id"
    t.index ["service_id"], name: "index_bookings_on_service_id"
  end
```

When I run guard which runs a `consistency_fail` test which fails with:

```
There are calls to has_one that aren't backed by unique indexes.
----------------------------------------------------------------
Model          Table Columns
----------------------------------------------------------------
Service  bookings (service_id)
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now originally I didn't have `unique: true` but I rolled back and added it in, still the same problem, again, didn't have `index: true` so I rolled back and added that in and still the same problem.

I think it's becuase `service_id` in the schema doesn't have `unique: true` on it but I don't know and I can't find any information on my specific problem.

What causes this problem, what am I doing that is causing this problem and what can I do to stop this problem, given the current migration?

Comment: Where on the internet did you read that you can pass this parameter like `t.references unique: true`? The uniqueness is a property of the index, not the reference itself. So for example, you *can* pass the parameter like that for `t.add_index`: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_index

Comment: @TomLord To be honest, I don't know and also my rails-fu is still less then stellar.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
t.references :service, foreign_key: true, dependent: :destroy, index: {unique: true}
```

More about [creating references](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_reference)

Comment: This worked, so thanks, question, is it possible in future to make so I can change it from `has_one` to `has_many` if needed?

Comment: You can change, but can not create more than one assigned object: evoke ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique

Comment: @Thermatix If you think it should be a `has_many`, then I'd make that change sooner rather than later. It could be a real pain to update a large application to use `booking.services` instead of `booking.service` all over the place; the implications are non-trivial.